# Must appear in Group By clause or used in agg. function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a large User table and I'm trying to group all users within a town by street and get a count via postgres & rails.  The following gives me the right data however I'm wondering if I could get a better output:

```
User.group(:town,:street).count ###Gives a large hash of key/value pairs with town_name repeated each time for every grouped street like {['TOWN_NAME', 'STREET_NAME']=>'#ofUsers'}
```

So instead of this: `{['BETHPAGE', 'JACKSON AVE']=>372, ['BETHPAGE', 'WILLIAM ST']=>28}`

I'd like `{ 'BETHPAGE'=>{['JACKSON', 372],['WILLIAM ST', 28]} }`

Is there a better query that would output this information in a format that the TOWN_NAME would be used once as a key and each street and its count are given in an array like:

```
{ 'TOWN_NAME' => {['STREET_NAME', '#ofUsers'], ['STREET_NAME', '#ofUsers']}
```

Comment: You would either have to change your SQL query, or you could probably transform the map directly using Ruby code.

Comment: Yes I think iterating via Ruby might be the only option but I was hoping to avoid that since the result set may be large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group it using ruby

```
original = User.group(:town, :street).count
grouped = original.group_by { |vals, count| vals[0] }
grouped.each do |town, matches| 
  grouped[town] = matches.map { |vals, count| [vals.second, count] }
end

grouped # => { 'TOWN_NAME' => [['STREET_NAME', '#ofUsers'], ['STREET_NAME', '#ofUsers']] }
```

I was looking for a way of doing it in a plain query but you would need multiple calls to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the help I didn't think there was a good way getting it from the db in one shot either. Just add the closing bracket to "[vals.second, count". Thanks again