# Get tow bidimensional hash from bidimensional activerecord group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get a a bidimensional hash from a activerecord group request like this.

```
MachineFailure.group("machine.key", "failure.name").sum("timestampdiff(hour, machine_failures.created_at, closed_at)")
```

this returns me a hash like:

> {["R01", "Corrective Maintenance"]=>3, ["R01", "Auto reboot"]=>8}

when I actually need something like this:

> {"R01" => {"Corrective Maintentance" => 3, "Auto reboot" => 8}}

thx

Comment: Hello @Diego, welcome to StackOverflow. This question is a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53156982/8304905) it was asked a couple of hours before yours, please do research before posting your question. Help us keep the quality of the site.

Comment: thx, works perfectly, just make some modificaciones for hash instead of array, but works perectly.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53157432/8304905) is exactly what you need.

In short, you need to map the hash that is returned after the call to the database.